# Strings sometimes not retrieved with Cloud Datastore query (GAE, JDO, Endpoints, Java)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints, jdo

I have a problem with retrieving objects from Google Cloud Datastore using JDO. It is incredibly frustrating, because 99.5% of the time my code works perfectly, but 0.5% of the time some of the data is missing, and I can't find consistent steps to replicate the bug. I'm fairly certain that my issue is with either how I've set up my model or how I'm querying the datastore (I have a suspicion that it may be to do with lazy loading or the default fetch group, but I'm not sure).

Before I explain what's happening it would help to understand the model.

Here is a simplified version of my model:

```
@PersistenceCapable
@Inheritance(customStrategy = "complete-table") 
public class DataObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY, defaultFetchGroup="true")
    protected Key theKey;

    @Persistent()
    protected String name;
    //...
}

@PersistenceCapable
public class Class1 extends DataObject{

    @Persistent()
    @Element(dependent="true")
    private List<Class2> listOfClass2 = new ArrayList<Class2>();
    //...   
}

@PersistenceCapable
public class Class2 extends DataObject{

    @Persistent()
    @Element(dependent="true")
    private List<Class3> listOfClass2 = new ArrayList<Class3>();
    //...   
}

@PersistenceCapable
public class Class3 extends DataObject{

    @Persistent()
    private String value;
    //...
}
```

And here is the code used to query the data store:

```
public class DataManager {
    public DataObject get(
        User user,
        Class type,
        Long id) throws OAuthRequestException
    {
        PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
       DataObject obj = null;

        try
        {
            obj = mgr.getObjectById(type, id);
            getAllChildren(obj);
        } 
        finally 
        {
            mgr.close();
        }

        if(obj != null)
        {
            return obj; 
        }
        else
        {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Entity not found");
        }        
    }

    /** 
     * Returns all of the children of the given object
     * and their children etc. It is intended to 'touch' every object
     * in the tree to accommodate for lazy loading.
     */
    private List<StoredDataObject> getAllChildren(DataObject obj)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

The problem is that very occasionally, the query will be returned with all of the 'name' fields at a given level empty. For instance, If I retrieve an object of Class1, all of the child Class2 objects will have the 'name' attribute equal to "". The data is definitely in the data store because if I run the query again they will be populated correctly. I have never seen any of the other attributes empty, only the name field. Sometimes it occurs at the Class2 level, sometimes Class3, but never Class1 (as far as I have seen).

It is my understanding that any String attributes should automatically be included in the default fetch group, but am I possibly missing an annotation that forces the 'name' attribute to be retrieved every time?

New observation: When this occurs, it will happen consistently for about 15 minutes as long as I run the same query with the same user credentials. Could this be something to do with caching?

Comment: why would it be due to lazy loading or the dfg? a String field is in the DFG. More likely due to the "oddities" of the datastore you're using. Perhaps look at the log

Comment: I'm not sure, perhaps I'm on the wrong track looking at those. There's nothing in the logs that suggests a problem as far as I can see

Comment: I don't know Java, but are you taking eventual consistency into account?

Comment: Yeah, this occurs even on data that was persisted days earlier and I can run the same query before and after without error.